# Print my wx.Panel after formatting it

Tags: python, wxpython

I am working on an app using wxPython and it kind of needs to print the info shown to the user. On click of the `print` button, The data shown in the current panel has to be formatted a bit and then be sent to the printer queue.

Google searches give me ways to print text documents. How do I go about with this?

Comment: Looking at your (minimal) code might be helpful. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

wxPython provides a couple of printing options. You can check out the full printing framework it provides here:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/printing_framework_overview.html
- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Printout.html

It's fairly complex, but it is also the most flexible way to print using wxPython. They do have another option though that's called HtmlEasyPrinting:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html.HtmlEasyPrinting.html

You might want to take a look at that if you're new to wxPython. Of course, you could also use the [reportlab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab) package to generate a nicely formatted PDF of your text and then send that to the printer or just open it in the user's default PDF viewer so they can print it.